# Sorting both a string array and a double array from highest to lowest(parallel arrays) and aligning the text

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, double

Alright I'll bite, this program does sort the number from highest to lowest **but** it'll only sort  if the numbers are arranged in order from highest to lowest;not if it's sporadic. Here are two example of what I mean.

Example 1: 12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.

Example 2: 32,25,24,31,10,11,15,16,8,19,18,5.

You see how in example 2 that some of the numbers are in order like 32 25 24 but some of the others are not. This is my main problem. My secondary problem is aligning the text vertically so that it looks neat. Should I use setw left, right for this? Please give feedback.

Note 1: The IDE that I'm using is codeblocks.

Note 2: Keep in mind that whatever number the user inputs for a particular month has to be vertically parallel to each.

Note 3: I'm pretty sure the problem is with my selection sort. So you really should be looking at the function **void selectionsort** since that is the function that is doing all the sorting. I just don't know where I went wrong with my sorting though. Everything else seems to be in order.

```
/* This program lets the user enter the total rainfall
for each month into an array of doubles. The program also
calculates and displays the total rainfall for a year, the average
monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest and lowest amounts.
The program also displays the list of months, sorted in order of
rainfall from highest to lowest.*/

/* This program does not accept negative numbers for monthly rainfall
   figures.*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void SelectionSort(string[], double[], int);// Function Protoype.

int main()
{
  const int SIZE = 12; /* A constant integer that represent the total
                   amount of months in a year. */

  double totalRainfallPerMonth[SIZE]; /* Loop this array to force the user
                                         to enter variables for each
                                         element in this array. */

  double totalRainfallPerYear = 0; /* The total amount of rainfall
                                      (in inches) per year. */

  // An array of every month.
  string monthArray[SIZE]={"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
                           "June", "July","August", "September",
                           "October", "November", "December"};

  double average; // A variable that holds the average monthly rainfall.

  int i; // Will be used as a counter for any loop.

  cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); // Set decimal notation.

  for(i=0; i<=11; i++)
 {
   // Prompt the user to enter values.
   cout << "Please enter the total rainfall(in inches) for ";
   cout << monthArray[i] << ": ";
   cin >> totalRainfallPerMonth[i];

   while(totalRainfallPerMonth[i] < 0) /* If the user enters a negative
                                      value */
  {
   cerr << "No negative values allowed. "; // Display error message.
   cout << "Please try again. ";
   cin >> totalRainfallPerMonth[i];
  }
}

for(i=0; i<=11; i++)
{
      // Calculate the total rainfall for a year.
      totalRainfallPerYear += totalRainfallPerMonth[i];
}

// Display the total rainfall for a year.
cout << "\nThe total rainfall this year is " << totalRainfallPerYear;
cout << " inches of rain. " << endl;

// Calculate the average monthly rainfall.
average = totalRainfallPerYear / SIZE;

// Display the average
cout << "\nThe average monthly rainfall per month is ";
cout << average;
cout << " inches of rain. " << endl << endl << endl;

cout << "\n" << "Month " << "\t";
cout << "        Rainfall(in inches)" << endl;
cout << "-----------------------------------";

SelectionSort(monthArray, totalRainfallPerMonth, SIZE); /* Call in the
                                                       function. */

return 0;
}


void SelectionSort(string month[], double rain[], int SIZE)
{
   int i;
   int j;

   int min;

for (i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
 {
    min = i; // The intial subscript or the first element.

     for (j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++)
     {
        if (rain[j] > rain[min])  /* if this element is greater,
                                       then it is the new minimum */
         {
            min = j;

             // swap both variables at the same times
             double tempDouble = rain[i];
             rain[i] = rain[j];
             rain[j] = tempDouble;

             string tempString = month[i];
             month[i] = month[j];
             month[j] = tempString;
         }
     }
 }

for(i=0; i<=11; i++)
 {
    /* Display the amount of rainfall per month from highest to
       lowest */

    cout << "\n" << month[i] << "\t" << rain[i] << endl;
 }
}
```

Comment: Unless it is to rewrite `sort`, I would use a `struct RainFallForMonth { double rainfall; int month;};` and do `std::sort` with custom comparer.

Comment: One of my friends was telling me to do structure but we haven't learned structure in our class yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in fact an error in your selection sort implementation: you are swapping elements too early and too often.

Only after you have performed a full sweep over the whole remaining array and therefore have determined the global minimum (I keep that term in order to be consistent with the variable name and the comments in the code, although in fact you are looking for the maximum) you should perform a single swap of the first element of the remaining array with the minimum element.

The corrected code (only the main loop of the sorting function shown) should look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
{
    min = i; // The intial subscript or the first element.

    for (j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (rain[j] > rain[min])  /* if this element is greater,
                                     then it is the new minimum */
        {
            min = j;
        }
    }   

    // swap both variables at the same times
    double tempDouble = rain[i];
    rain[i] = rain[min];
    rain[min] = tempDouble;

    string tempString = month[i];
    month[i] = month[min];
    month[min] = tempString;
}
```

Comment: Wow nice job in catching that error. I'll  make sure not to do the same error again.

Comment: Also I should change min to max since, like you said, I'm looking for the maximum value in each element of the array.